# What are those Projects on my google console?

Tags: console, cloud, project, account, ripple

Hello does anyone know what are those projects I found them on my google account. Picture is attached.

[Projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QITlI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Those projects are the belonging to your organization, that's the reason why you're seeing them in the "all" section.

if you want to lists all active projects, where the active account has Owner, Editor, Browser or Viewer permissions. Projects are listed in alphabetical order by project name please follow the instructions [in this link.](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/list)